# Proving $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)\sin{x}dx \geq \pi - 2$ given a twice differentiable function and an initial inequality condition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, derivatives

> Let $f : [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function such that $(f^{''}(x) - f(x))\tan{x} + 2f^{'}(x) \geq 1, \forall x \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$. Prove that $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)\sin{x}dx \geq \pi - 2$.

The given inequality does not seem very generous, so what I tried to do, seeing that we need to obtain $\sin{x}$ and we have a $\tan{x}$ inside the inequality, was to process it by rearranging terms and eventually obtaining $f(x)\sin{x}$ on one side. Therefore:

$(f^{''}(x) - f(x))\tan{x} \geq 1 - 2f^{'}(x) \Leftrightarrow (f^{''}(x) - f(x))\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}} \geq 1 - 2f^{'}(x)$

At this stage, since we only really care about $I = (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}) \subset \mathbb{R}$, we know that $\cos{x} > 0, \forall x \in I$, but $\sin{x}$ takes both negative, positive and a null value, therefore we cannot multiply by it. We can, however, multiply by $cos{x}$, unaffecting our inequality. We obtain:

$(f^{''}(x) - f(x))\sin{x} \geq (1 - 2f^{'}(x))\cos{x} \Leftrightarrow f^{''}(x)\sin{x} - f(x)\sin{x} \geq \cos{x} - 2f^{'}(x)\cos{x}$

By rearranging and isolating the $f(x)\sin{x}$ terms, we finally obtain that:

$f(x)\sin{x} \leq 2f^{'}(x)\cos{x} + f^{''}(x)\sin{x} - \cos{x}, \forall x \in I$

The problem with this inequality is that we have a $\leq$, but we need a $\geq$. Knowing this is true for all $x \in I$, it must also remain true for every $-x \in I$, therefore we map $x \rightarrow -x$ in our inequality, to obtain:

$-f(-x)\sin{x} \leq 2f^{'}(-x)\cos{x} - f^{''}(-x)\sin{x} - \cos{x}$

Denote $J = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)\sin{x}dx$. It is known that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx$. Therefore, substituting $u = -x$ in J, we obtain that $J = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(-x)\sin{(-x)}dx = -\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(-x)\sin{x}dx$, since sine is an odd function.

However, this is where I am lost; I do not exactly know how to turn the sign from $\leq$ to $\geq$, even with my substitution idea. Another thing I noticed is that the $f^{'}(x)\cos{x} + f^{''}(x)\sin{x}$ term can be written as $(f^{'}(x)\sin{x})^{'}$, but the constant term $2$ is particularly annoying.

Any help, hints, ideas, or solutions would be of tremendous use to me. Thank you very much for your time! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function
$$
 g(x) = f(x) \sin x + \cos x
$$
on the interval $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$. We have, following [insipidintegrator's hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4644939/42969) and using the given inequality,
$$
\begin{align}
 g''(x) &= (f''(x)-f(x))\sin x+2f'(x)\cos x - \cos x \\
 &= \cos x \left( (f''(x)-f(x))\tan x+2f'(x) - 1\right) \\
 &\ge 0 \, ,
\end{align}
$$
which shows that $g$ is *convex.* Then we use that the graph of a convex function lies above the tangent line at the graph at $x=0$:
$$
 g(x) \ge g(0) + x g'(0) = 1 + xf(0)
$$
and therefore
$$
 f(x) \sin x \ge 1 + x f(0) - \cos x \, .
$$
Integration now gives the desired result.

Note that the value of $f(0)$ is not known, but also not needed, since $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} x \, dx = 0$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you used convexity to obtain $g(x) \geq g(0) + xg^{’}(0)$? I mean it is easy to see why it works on [0, x] because of Lagrange’s mean value theorem: $\frac{g(x) - g(0)}{x} = g’(c) \geq g’(0)$, but does it also hold for negative values?

Comment: @MorărescuMihnea: For negative $x$ is $\frac{g(x) - g(0)}{x} = g’(c) \le g’(0)$, and multiplying by $x$ reverses the inequality sign. So you have $g(x) - g(0) \ge x g'(0)$ in any case.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $$(f''(x)-f(x))\sin x+2f'(x)\cos x=(f''(x)\sin x+f'(x)\cos x)+(f'(x)\cos x-f(x)\sin x)$$$$=(f'(x)\sin x)'+(f(x)\cos x)'=(f'(x)\sin x+f(x)\cos x)'$$$$=(f(x)\sin x)''.$$

Comment: From your hint, I deduced that $(f(x)\sin{x})^{''} \geq \cos{x}, \forall x \in I$. However, how would I proceed about showing that $J \geq \pi - 2$? I tried integrating by parts multiple times but it does not work (keeping $f(x)\sin{x}$ as a function and choosing $(x)^{'}$ as the other one). I also cannot simply integrate this inequality three times. Should I maybe denote $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} (f(t)\sin{t})^{''}dt$ and integrate $F(x) \geq \int_{0}^{x} \cos{t}dt$ and proceed likewise multiple times to obtain an inequality for $f(x)\sin{x}$ which I can then integrate on the interval I?

Comment: Following your given hint, I came back to the problem and since $(f(x)\sin{x})'' \geq \cos{x}, \forall x \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$, we can integrate this inequality to obtain $f(x)\sin{x} \geq -\cos{x}$ and $(f(x)\sin{x})' \geq \sin{x}$ respectively. Setting $g(x) = f(x)\sin{x} + \cos{x}$, we obtain that $g'(x) \geq 0$, thus $g$ is increasing, and for $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2}), g(x) \geq 1$. However, I am not able to show that for the other interval. ($g(x) \geq 1$ follows from $g(x) \geq g(0) = 1$)

Comment: It would be useful to prove this for the other interval as well because then we deduce that $f(x)\sin{x} \geq 1 - \cos{x}, \forall x \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$, which means that $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f(x)\sin{x}dx \geq \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(1-\cos{x})dx = \pi - 2$